# Error empty value when convert code from php to twig format

Tags: php, twig

I have a sample code php

```
<?php 
echo isset($dealer_special[$dealer['customer_group_id']][$type['product_type_id']]['percent_sale']) ? $dealer_special[$dealer['customer_group_id']][$type['product_type_id']]['percent_sale'] : ''; 
?>
```

Convert to twig

```
{{ dealer_special.dealer.customer_group_id.type.product_type_id.percent_sale ? dealer_special.dealer.customer_group_id.type.product_type_id.percent_sale : '' }}
```

How to fix it

Answer (score 1):

You didn't nest that correctly:

```
{{ dealer_special[dealer.customer_group_id][type.product_type_id].percent_sale|default }}
```

Instead you should split this to separate variables so it's more verbose and easier to comprehend and maintain:

```
{% set customerGroup = dealer.customer_group_id %}
{% set productTypeId = type.product_type_id %}
{% set dealerSpecial = dealer_special[customerGroup][productTypeId] %}
{{ dealerSpecial.percentSale }}
```